# Background-Image behind width of body content

Tags: css, background-image

I'm attemping search any answer of my problem, but without. 
Have Body selector that's have max-width: 85%, and some selector that's header and I want it's background image get 100% of width - behind body selector attribute.

HTML Code -

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div></div>
   </header>
</body>
```

CSS Code -

```
body {  
  width: 85%;
}

.header {
        display:flex;
        position: relative;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        background-image: url(../assets/header-bg.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center 120%;
        background-size: cover;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 10% 0 10% 0;

.header::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your selector is wrong. You are not selecting the *class* `header` but the element, so you do not need a class selector `.`. Second, you probably want to set your header to the full width of the screen? To do so you can use viewport units. 100vw is the full width of the viewport, 1vw is 1/100th of it. You would then still have to move the header to the left to compensate for its initial position inside body.

Your code would look like this:

```css
body {
  width: 85%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background-image: url(../assets/header-bg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 120%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10% 0 10% 0;
  /* here */
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: 7.5vw;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div></div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for but if it's not then please clarify your question:

Instead of making the body 85% width, just make it 100% and apply the background to the body, this way the background will have 100% width and the header 85% width.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div></div>
    </header>
</body>
```

---

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../assets/header-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    height: 10%;
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10% 0 10% 0;
}
```